# Adding an image to a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add an image to a button, but I have got some issues when I try to execute the current code. All it shows is an image with no words. I can't even see the button either. Is there some way of fixing my current code?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="giftest.gif")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", image=imagetest)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `pack` (or `grid`) your button in the window, here is how you could do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage

def print_hello():
    print('hello')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="giftest.gif")

button_qwer = tk.Button(root, text="asdfasdf", image=imagetest, command=print_hello)
button_qwer.pack()   # <-- don't forget to place the button in the window

root.mainloop()
```

You can have **both text and image displayed** on your button, using the `compound` option, like this:

```
button_qwer = tk.Button(root, image=imagetest, text="asdfasdf", compound="top", command=print_hello)
```

`compound` options are `bottom`, `center`, `left`, `none`, `right`, or `top`

Comment: By the way, is it actually possible in Python to get buttons that have both the image and the text? I was initially intending for a method of getting both the image and the text showing, but at least I got my button to show an image. Currently, I've got only the image showing up.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, like this: `button_qwer = tk.Button(root, image=imagetest, text="asdfasdf", command=print_hello, compound="top")`

Answer (score 0):

You are making the button successfully but you are not drawing it onto the screen/interface. Use `pack` , `place` or `grid`.

```
button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", image=imagetest)
button_qwer.pack()
```

Your full code can be like:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="giftest.gif")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

button_qwer = Button(root, text="asdfasdf", image=imagetest)
button_qwer.pack()
root.mainloop()
```