# I don't even know how to describe this problem

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to insert a pic into a tkinter button 
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageOps

class main_class(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.window.configure(background='grey')

        #opening play pic and resizing it to fit into button
        self.play_pic = Image.open("play_pic.jpg")
        self.play_pic_size = (11,49)
        self.play_pic = ImageOps.fit(self.play_pic,self.play_pic_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.play_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.play_pic)


        #play button
        self.play_button = Button(self.window,image=self.play_pic,command = self.play,height =11 ,width = 49).place(x=800,y = 180)


        self.window.mainloop()

    def play(self):
        print('Everything is working fine so far')


#creating an object
object = main_class()
object.play()
```

This is what the result should look like :

[image]

And this is what is happening :
[image]

This is the "play_pic.jpg" in case you need it:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250213/adding-an-image-to-a-button-in-tkinter answer your question?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Unfortunately no

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066202/12744275

Comment: @Renaud Doesn't work either :C

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly creating an image only 11 pixels wide, why do you expect it to be bigger?

Comment: @BryanOakley Even if I change the 11 to 1000 I get the same result

Comment: Did you change it in both places? And did you change the y value also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code. First, you're trying to convert the image to be only 11 pixels wide by 49 pixels tall with these statements:

```
    self.play_pic_size = (11,49)
    self.play_pic = ImageOps.fit(self.play_pic,self.play_pic_size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Second, regardless of the image size, you're forcing the button to be a width of 11 pixels and height of 49 pixels:

```
    self.play_button = Button(...,height =11 ,width = 49  ).place(x=800,y = 180)
```

If you're going to the trouble of resizing the image to be what you want, there is no need to request the button be a specific size. It will automatically shrink or expand to fit the image.

The first step is to define `self.play_pic_size` to be a reasonable size. Next, *remove* `height =11 ,width = 49` from the button definition.