# Is there a way to make Entry widgets in tkinter rounded or look nicer?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, photoimage

I code in Python and I use tkinter quite a lot to create GUIs for my applications. I prefer to make my GUIs look round and modern rather than sharp cornered boxes. For buttons and labels I tend to use PhotoImage to use self-made images that provide a cleaner look.

My GUIs look really modern now but the only issue is that I have Entry widgets for users to enter data. They still look really boxy and rectangular, which makes them stand out from the rest of the modern look. My question is, that is there a method in tkinter like PhotoImage, that makes the Entry Widget look better?

This is the current way I make entry widgets:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I say make entries look nicer I mean:

- Smoother Corners
- Rounded Edges
- Just a less boxy look

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: The `ttk` widget look more "modern". Give them a try.

Comment: What is that? And how do I use it?

Comment: `from tkinter import ttk`, then `e = ttk.Entry(root)`.

Comment: I have tried this but it says “unknown option -fg”

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52250213/adding-an-image-to-a-button-in-tkinter

Comment: `foreground` should be used instead of `fg` for `ttk.Entry`.  Note that `ttk` widget normally uses `ttk.Style` class to style widget, see official [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html).

Comment: I have tried this and it looks better but is there a way to make it look rounded.

Comment: CustomTkinter can do rounded corners and much more: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/

Answer (score 0):

U can place ur sharp corner image & place your tkinter entry on it , sure to add entry bg color same as images color.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

#read image for entry  
entry_bg_image=PhotoImage(
file=r"file.extension")

#add frame for entry
entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.pack()

#place your rounded corner image.    
#for entry bg
entry_bg =tk.Label(entry_frame,
image=entry_bg_image)
entry_bg.place(rely=0 ,relx=0)

#place entry
entry = tk.Entry(entry_frame
        ,bg=same_as_image)
entry.place(relx=0,rely=0)
root.mainloop()
```